# Html5 Canvas save div as image (text is showing in image but not images)

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas

I am trying to take snapshot of div using html5 canvas. When I try to take a snapshot of div with only text data inside it works fine. But when I try to snapshot an image inside div it shows blank white image and text.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
            html2canvas($("#mydiv"), {
             onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("body").append(canvas);
             }
        });  
    }
   </script>

<div id="mydiv" style="height:400px; width:300px; " >
<img src="noname.jpg">
<p>Very good iamge</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I assume you have checked that the image has loaded correctly before triggering `capture()`. Try either adding a `/` before the image name, or giving the image a full path.

Comment: I should have added - make sure the function is not running before the images have loaded.  Try wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() {` - or, for a test, trigger it with a button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html2canvas will not display images that originated in another domain:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html

Comment: thanks you gave me accurate answer even though i didn't mention that i was using image from other domain.